# TabLayout in the fragment is shadowed by activity's title bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-tablayout

I have an `Activity` with 4 tabs. The `TabLayout` is placed at the bottom (I know this is a violation of guidelines, but that's the design). One of the `Fragment` also has tabs which should be placed at the top, but it's shadowed by the title bar.

[image].

How can I add tabs to `Fragment`, so that it's not shadowed by the Toolbar?

Here is `activity_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_main_tabs"
        app:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and `fragment_with_tabs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/clothes_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/clothes_fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `app:elevation="@dimen/elevation"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the elevation to 0. Setting the elevation from the `AppBarLayout` is ideal but anyway you can do something like this

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: thanks! but how do I return the elevation back, when other fragments are visible? do I have to call setElevation in each of them?

Comment: Ya. You need to set the elevation on each for customized elevated behaviour. Please accept and upvote the answer if helpful.